# Dygraphs - more advanced plots are not showing

Tags: r, r-dygraphs

When I plot basic graphs there aren't any issues, however when I try to plot something like `dyBarSeries()`, it plots the points on the graph and shows them when I pass with the cursor, however no barplots are generated.

Here is a reproducible example taken straight from the dygraphs for R GitHub pages:

```
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths) %>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>%
  dyBarSeries('fdeaths') %>% 
  dyFilledLine('mdeaths')
```

I am supposed to get this:

[image: regular dygraph]

But instead I get this:

[image: my dygraph]

What can be causing this? I also tried rstudio.cloud to check whether it was my R installation and packages, and I got the same results. However, when ran the example code from my work computer and had no issues, worked flawlessly. The problem should be local to my R install or PC, but I had the same issues on rstudio.cloud.

Comment: Try disabling hardware acceleration in your browser settings

Comment: Thanks but did not work. Ran the code from my work pc however, and had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives the desired output.

```
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths) %>%
#  dyBarSeries('fdeaths') %>% 
#  dyFilledLine('mdeaths') %>% 
  dyRangeSelector()
```

Comment: This works on my pc, but I wanted one of the series to plot as bars :/ I ran the dygraphs example code on my work pc and it worked perfectly, no issues. So I guess the issue is due to my R install or pc.